# How to trigger a computed function after typing in input field in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Now I am using the following code. When I use @change it is not working?

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Longitude</label>
  <input id="lngVillage" 
         type="text" 
         class="form-control" 
         placeholder="Longitude of Village" 
         name="lngVillage" 
         required="" 
         v-model="lng" 
         pattern="^[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$" 
         maxlength="7" 
         oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter a valid Longitude')"
         oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
  </div>
 </div>
<div v-if="isDisabled == false">
</div>
```

My computed function is

```
 computed: {
  isDisabled() {
      if (this.lng.length > 5) {
        axios.get('url')
          .then(response => {
          })
          .catch(e => {
            this.errors.push(e)
          })
      } else {
        return true;
      }
  }
 },
```

After typing in the input field I need to call isDisabled(). Please help me to have a solution.

Comment: `isDisabled()` is computed property so it is getting called everytime input is changed. What else do you want.

Comment: is it possible to call isDiabled at input change

Comment: Isn't it getting called already on the input with v-model="lng". console.log() in your isDisabled it will get logged everytime input is changed

Comment: Sir, if I remove this code, <div v-if="isDisabled == false">
</div> I am not getting the same

Comment: You can't use async logic in computed properties, unless you use something like: https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed

Comment: I see you are using `v-model` here. There is no need for `@change`

Answer (score 2):

There are more ways to approach this. You can solve it using the computed setter but I believe that watchers would be more appropriate here. Set a watch on the lng data using the following code.

```
computed: {
  isDisabled() {
      return (this.lng.length > 5) ? true : false
  }
},
watch: {
  lng: function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue.length > 5 && this.lar.length > 5) {
      this.executeCall();
    }
  },
  lar: function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue.length > 5 && this.lng.length > 5) {
      this.executeCall();
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  executeCall() {
    axios
      .get("url")
      .then(response => {})
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e);
      });
  }
}
```

For more details please refer to https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers.

Comment: Sir, How to solve using computed. Sir, if I remove this code, <div v-if="isDisabled == false"> </div> I am not getting the same in my code

Comment: Sir, i have a lat and lng input field, how to trigger using your code. I have two input fields as lar and lng, On changing both I need to trigger, how could this happen

Comment: I updated the answer to take both lar and lng into consideration. If I understood you correctly, what you need to do is check if both lar and lng have inputs larger than 5( this is your scenario as I understood ). And div needs to be hidden if lng is smaller.

Comment: sir, is there any way to remove <div v-if="isDisabled == false"> </div> code,

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you want to accomplish. Maybe update the question so that everyone here understands what you want to do. Regarding your initial question about triggering something on input change, the code above will do that.